# Need help getting rid of the horizontal scrollbar on my website.

Tags: css, web, scrollbar

My website now has a horizontal scrollbar. I can not figure out why it is there but can anyone please help me fix this problem.

Here is my website link for everyone to check it out.

http://mchubcraft.com/

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with your #headguy420 div.

You can absolute position him like you are but you should set his width to the width of the background image you are using, the width 100% + your absolute positioning is causing the problem

Answer (score 0):

Update your css to the following. This should resolve your issue.

```
#jsn-header {
background-color: #404040;
color: #ccc;
box-shadow: 0 5px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.4) inset;
position: relative;/*-----added css---*/
}
#headguy420 {
position: absolute;
left: 1020px;
top: -20px;
width: 100%;
height: 300px;
background: url(/templates/jsn_escape_free/images/headguy.png) no-repeat;
z-index: 999;/*-----added css---*/
}
```